# NoneType object is not callable | Python Printing regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to clean up some data I've scraped from twitter but am getting an error *TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable*, when I try to print out the text of the stamp_print variable (just a simple time stamp.) I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re  

my_url = "https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()


page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

tweets = page_soup.findAll("p",{"class":"TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--normal js-tweet-text tweet-text"})
time_stamp = page_soup.find_all("a",{"class":"tweet-timestamp"})

i = 0
for tweet in tweets:
    stamp = time_stamp[i]
    stamp_print = stamp.match('[0-9]+\s\w+|[0-9]+\sw+')
    print(stamp_print.get_text)
    i+=1
    print('---------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print(tweet.get_text())
    print('\n')
```

Comment: Try `print(re.findall(r'\d+\s*\w+', stamp.get_text))` after `stamp = time_stamp[i]`. Note `stamp` does not have `match` method.

Comment: make sure that stamp_print is not None

Comment: Your regex doesn't produce the results you're intending. Which exact part of the timestamp are you looking to extract?

Answer (score -1):

This ended up working thanks.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re  

my_url = "https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()


page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

tweets = page_soup.findAll("p",{"class":"TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--normal js-tweet-text tweet-text"})
time_stamp = page_soup.find_all("a",{"class":"tweet-timestamp"})

i = 0
for tweet in tweets:
    stamp = time_stamp[i]
    print(re.findall(r'[0-9]+\s\w+|\w+\s[0-9]+', stamp.get_text())) 
    i+=1
    print('---------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print(tweet.get_text())
    print('\n')
```